# Memory leak when uploading an image to texture with CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, opengl-es, core-video

I debugged with Instruments, but I cannot find it:

```
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer;
    CVReturn err = CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes(kCFAllocatorDefault, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA, _outputFrame.data, 4 * IMAGE_WIDTH, dataReleaseCallback, NULL, NULL, &pixelBuffer);

    if(!pixelBuffer || err) {
      NSLog(@"CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes failed (error: %d)", err);
      return;
    }

    CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _backgroundTextureCache, pixelBuffer, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &_backgroundTextureRef);
    _backgroundTexture = CVOpenGLESTextureGetName(_backgroundTextureRef);
    [_frameLock unlock];
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _backgroundTexture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Then in the OpenGL draw method, after the draw call:

```
...
CFRelease(_backgroundTextureRef);
_backgroundTextureRef = NULL;
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheFlush(_backgroundTextureCache, 0);
```

I tried to deallocate the pixel buffer manually, but then it fails in the callback `dataReleaseCallback` of `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I don't know what else could be leaking there.

**UPDATE**:

I commented out the body of the callback:

```
inline void dataReleaseCallback(void *releaseRefCon, const void *baseAddress)
{
//  free((void *)baseAddress);
}
```

And now I can call:

```
CVPixelBufferRelease(_pixelBuffer);
```

without any error and the memory leak is fixed. The question that arises is what is the utility of that callback then?

Comment: That title makes we want to close this question ASAP.

Comment: Are you releasing `pixelBuffer` anywhere?

Comment: @karlphillip better?

Comment: @aledalgrande MUCH BETTER.

Comment: @RetoKoradi no, if I do, I get an error from `dataReleaseCallback`, as stated in the last paragraph.